# Regex for validate number to 2 decimal places

Tags: c#, regex

I need some **regex** that will match *only numbers* that are decimal to *two places*. For example

```
   123 : Match
12.123 : No match
 12.34 : Match
```

Comment: Does `12.3` match?

Comment: If you want to match *at most* `2` *decimal places*: `^\-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean *at most* `2` decimal points then you can try

```
^\-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

pattern

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
   "123",
   "12.123",
   "12.34",
   "12.3",
 };

string pattern = @"^\-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$";

var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,7} : {(Regex.IsMatch(test, pattern) ? "Match" : "No match")}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

Outcome:

```
    123 : Match
 12.123 : No match
  12.34 : Match
   12.3 : Match
```

If you mean no fractional part at all or *exactly* `2` digits:

```
^\-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

Outcome:

```
    123 : Match
 12.123 : No match
  12.34 : Match
   12.3 : No match
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you don't need regex, take this as an example.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] tests = new string[] {
            "123",               // false
            "12.123",            // false
            "12.34",             // true
            "12.3",              // false
            "abc.de",            // false
            "123,456.23"         // true
        };

        foreach (var test in tests)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ValidateDecimals(test)); 
        }

    }

    public static bool ValidateDecimals(string input)
    {
        if(!decimal.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, null, out _)) return false;

        var parts = input.Split('.');
        return parts.Length == 2 && parts[1].Length == 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Counter example: `"abc.de"`: you have to check that `parts` contain *digits only*

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko, caught it

Comment: Counter example (depends on current culture) `"123,456.23"`: we have `123,456` and `23` parts; `123,456.23`  will be successfully parsed as decimal since `,` is thousand (or even decimal) separator

Comment: you can check each `part` as `part.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')`

Comment: hmm actually checking part like that would be better than `NumberStyles` isnt it

Comment: culture is often a nuisance: for instance `(123)` for `-123` etc. that's why if we are told *only numbers* it's easier to check for digits

Comment: but we are told only numbers :D